# Failed to insert to a declared type table in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

my stored procedure failed to insert to a declared table type, there's already an insert query but when I `select * from @AktaFiducia` it's empty, can someone help me to identify what could I be doing wrong on the query below?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertFiducia]
@BatchNo Varchar(30),
@LoginID varchar(50),
@Message varchar(1000) output 
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN AKTAFiducia  
declare @AktaFiducia table
(
ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
BranchID varchar(3),
ApplicationID varchar(20),
SeqNo varchar(3),
AktaNo varchar(50),
AktaDate date,
CertificateNo varchar(50),
CertificateDate date,
InvoiceNo varchar(50),
InvoiceDate date,
InvoiceNote varchar(200),
FiduciaFee numeric(17,2),
BusinessDate Date,
ReceivedBy varchar(50),
NotaryID varchar(20),
AgreementNo varchar(20),
ServiceFee numeric(17,2),
FiduciaSeqNo int
)

insert into @AktaFiducia
select 
    fd.BranchID, 
    fd.ApplicationID,
    fd.AssetSeqNo,
    ufr.AktaNo,
    ufr.AktaDate,
    fd.CertificateNo,
    fd.CertificateDate,
    ufr.InvoiceNumber,
    ufr.InvoiceDate,
    fd.InvoiceNotes,
    NotaryCharge.AktaFee,
    GETDATE(),
    'Upload-System',
    fd.NotaryId,
    ufr.NoKontrak,
    NotaryCharge.ServiceFee,
    FiduciaSeqNo
from UploadFidusiaAktaRecieve ufr with (nolock)
inner join dbo.Agreement agr with (nolock) on agr.AgreementNo = ufr.NoKontrak
inner join dbo.Fiducia fd with (nolock) on fd.BranchID = agr.BranchID and fd.ApplicationID = agr.ApplicationID
and fd.AssetSeqNo = ufr.AssetSeqNo and ISNULL(fd.CustomerID,'') = ISNULL(ufr.CustomerID,'')
left join dbo.NotaryCharge with (nolock) on NotaryCharge.NotaryID = fd.NotaryId and TotalOTR between NotaryCharge.OTRFrom and NotaryCharge.OTRUntil
and AssetTypeID = case when ProductType ='DEMotor' then 'MOTOR' else 'MOBIL'end 
where IsProses = 0 and BatchNo = @BatchNo

select * from @AktaFiducia

SET @message = ''
COMMIT TRAN AKTAFiducia 
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRAN AKTAFiducia
    SET @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
END
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu nothing, which is confusing because when I select the `AktaFiducia` it's empty

Comment: does your `select` statement return something?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu the select statement is empty

Comment: well that explains...

Comment: @maSTAShuFu explain what?

Comment: do you think you can insert a data to a table where your source is empty?

Comment: @vin STOP applying a pattern mindlessly. A single statement is atomic - it either succeeds or fails as a whole. There is no reason to use a transaction here. Nor is there any reason to use a table variable. Remove all that crap and just include the select statement that you use to populate your table variable - NOTHING ELSE. And don't expect miracles if your select statement generates an empty resultset. If you want something different when that happens, you need to add code to accomplish that.